# Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Show me problem when run the app

this my code :
https://codeshare.io/eV6dyl

add abstract before class Login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: Container(child: Text("Login")),
    );
  }
  }

// Page Main.dart



void main(){
     runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Login(),
      routes:  {

      },
    );
  }
}
```

you made a mistake here:

```
  _LoginState creatState() => _LoginState();
```

it should be :

```
  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
```